# Why do I get "Invalid receiver type 'NSInteger'"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, primitive-types

Probably a simple question:
Why do I get an compiler warning for the following objective-C code?

```
//_classificationView.tag is a NSString

CGFloat imageWidth =  [_classificationView.tag floatValue] * 14.0;
```

And why does it say something about NSInteger?

Thanks for answers!
Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [`tag`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25) property is a `NSInteger` and not a class type. Just use the following instead:

```
CGFloat imageWidth =  _classificationView.tag * 14.0;
```

Comment: yeah, that works. strange - i thought i used the tag property to save a string a while ago. but maybe that's not true.
thank you!